# Appending path elements to an svg element without overwriting

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've got a visualization where I have already appended some svg path elements yet.
Then I perform some operations and I would like to append further svg path objects without overwriting the existing data.
How can I do that? If I just select all path elements and try to add the new elements, it does not work.

Cheers

DeepBlue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must select the parent of the svg paths, usually a group element `g` and use a key function to identify your data points, so the `enter()` method will add only the new data, and the `update()` method will update existing paths. There is an example of that in the article [Object Constancy](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/) explain this mechanism and have example code.